# using C types declared in .h file

Tags: c, cython, typedef, python-2.x

I want to use in my `.pyx` C types that are `typedef` declarated in my .h file:

```
//decls.h
typedef double Doub
typedef long int LInt
//etc...
```

My easy work around has been to redeclare them in my *.pxd (i.e. copy-paste that block of my `.h` into my `.pxd` replacing `typedef`-->`ctypedef`).
Now I'm using another `.h` with a lot of `typedef` statements, so I would like a more "cythonic" way of declaring.
I've been reading [this](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html), but did not help me.
Maybe something like?:

```
# .pxd cython file
cdef extern from "decls.h":
    Doub # no idea what to put before `Doub`
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is the `c` in `typedef` then you could use the C preprocessor to preprocess the `.h` file into a file that can be handled by cython. For example:

```
// a .c file:
#define CTYPEDEF typedef
#include "mytypes.h"

// the "mytypes.h" for cython preprocessing
#ifndef CTYPEDEF
# define CTYPEDEF ctypedef
#endif
CTYPEDEF ... myType;
```

In your makefile or IDE, make a rule to preprocess the .h file and then include the output into cython.

If there are more differences, you could proceeed in the same way and see this as an example.

Comment: nice but still I was wondering if there's some solution like `from "file.h" cimport ctype1, ctype2, ...` or some `cdef extern ...`

Comment: I wish there was a simpler alternative, as @jimmy described